# AWS site-to-site VPN - Security of the tunnels

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, vpn, firewall

It is described on AWS documentation that a site-to-site VPN involves the creation of two Tunnels between the virtual private gateway in AWS and the customer gateway on-premises. (See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html)

These two tunnels imply that two public IP addresses are allocated in AWS side for each one. My question is: how can I firewall this IP addresses on AWS side so they allow traffic only from the on-premises IP range?

It seems that neither Network ACLs nor Security Groups are useful for this, because both run inside the VPN, and at that point we are already past the VPN gateway.

So, how can I enforce security on the tunnels public IPs? Aren't they open for an attacker to try and guess the credentials and establish a tunnel of their own? (I know that this would include brute-forcing secrets, but still, sounds plausible).

Is this necessary? Or is there other layer of security that already takes care of this and I'm failing to see it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equipment listening on the public IPs of the tunnel endpoints is listening for traffic specifically from *your* customer gateway's assigned IP address with *your* VPN connection's keys.

> The internet-routable IP address for the customer gateway device's external interface -- The value must be static.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/adminguide/Introduction.html#DetermineNetworkInfo

A VPN connection you create won't negotiate tunnels with a gateway device using your credentials if it's using any other IP address than the one associated with your defined customer gateway device.

These same two external IP addresses on the AWS side may also be providing service to [other VPN connections](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpn-duplicate-tunnel-interface-ips/), in the interest of efficient use of IPv4 address space and perhaps other types of resources, but I mention this aspect only for completeness -- it has no implications of interest unless you are using the same customer gateway with the same IP address to connect to other VPCs in the region.   Each VPN connection (and thus access to your VPC) is constrained to a specific set of peer addresses  on each end, including the static IP of your customer gateway, and a specific set of pre-shared keys.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. One question, can you point to any AWS official docs that back up your explanation? I mean, the link you provided mentions that your customer gateway IP address needs to be static, but it doesn't explicity say "A VPN connection you create won't negotiate tunnels with a gateway device using your credentials if it's using any other IP address than the one associated with your defined customer gateway device." Can you provide further references for this? Thanks.

Comment: The [`CreateCustomerGateway` API action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateCustomerGateway.html) also makes the point that the address must be static.  I have not found any more explicitly documented clarification than this... but this is why a static IP is required at the CGW. The service definitely does not allow the IP of your customer gateway device to be anything other than configured.  You can confirm this for yourself -- take a firewall with a working configuration, change its external IP address, and it absolutely will not establish a tunnel to your VPC.

Comment: "unless you are using the same customer gateway with the same IP address to connect to other VPCs in the region." Thank you, this may explain some weirdness we get. I have a VP of Finance that likes to setup their own IT structures, and has a lot of problems getting VPN's to work. Never coordinates that. I wonder if he's backed into this setup.